# How to prevent bot from spamming embeds? Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, embed, spam-prevention, twitch

I have discord bot and it checks whether streamer is live or not. And I have a function that prevents it from spamming when someone is live:

```
if status is True:
                    async for message in channel.history(limit=2000):
                        if message.content == f"`Hey @everyone, {twitch_name} is live! Check it out:" + f"https://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}`":
                            break
                        else:
                            async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):

                                if member.id == int(user_id):
                                    await member.add_roles(role)
                            
                            await channel.send(f"`Hey @everyone, {twitch_name} is live! Check it out:" + f"https://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}`")

                            print(f"{user} started streaming. Sending a notification.")
                            break
```

And I wonder if there is the way to do same with embeds, but idk what to use. I though I can use `if embed = twitch_embed: break` instead of `if message.content`.
I want to send both message and embed when someone is live one time per stream each like mee6 does:

[image]

And I want to combine message and embed antispam function in the code. Please help! All my code here if you need:

```
import os
import json
import discord
import requests
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
from server import ping
from twitchAPI.twitch import Twitch
from discord.utils import get

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

# Authentication with Twitch API.
client_id = os.getenv('client_id')
client_secret = os.getenv('Dweller_token')
twitch = Twitch(client_id, client_secret)
twitch.authenticate_app([])
TWITCH_STREAM_API_ENDPOINT_V5 = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/{}"
API_HEADERS = {
    'Client-ID': client_id,
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json',
}

user_info = twitch.get_users(logins=['turb4ik'])
user_id = user_info['data'][0]['id']

print(user_info)


# Returns true if online, false if not.
def checkuser(user):
    try:
        userid = twitch.get_users(logins=[user])['data'][0]['id']
        url = TWITCH_STREAM_API_ENDPOINT_V5.format(userid)
        try:
            req = requests.Session().get(url, headers=API_HEADERS)
            jsondata = req.json()
            if 'stream' in jsondata:
                if jsondata['stream'] is not None:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error checking user: ", e)
            return False
    except IndexError:
        return False


# Executes when bot is started
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # Defines a loop that will run every 10 seconds (checks for live users every 10 seconds).
    @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def live_notifs_loop():
        # Opens and reads the json file
        with open('streamers.json', 'r') as file:
            streamers = json.loads(file.read())
        # Makes sure the json isn't empty before continuing.
        if streamers is not None:
            # Gets the guild, 'twitch streams' channel, and streaming role.
            guild = bot.get_guild(690995360411156531)
            channel = bot.get_channel(785523710362124298)
            role = get(guild.roles, id=835581408272580649)
            # Loops through the json and gets the key,value which in this case is the user_id and twitch_name of
            # every item in the json.
            for user_id, twitch_name in streamers.items():
                print("checking" + " " + str(twitch_name))
                # Takes the given twitch_name and checks it using the checkuser function to see if they're live.
                # Returns either true or false.
                status = checkuser(twitch_name)
                # Gets the user using the collected user_id in the json
                user = bot.get_user(int(user_id))
                # Makes sure they're live
                if status is True:
                    # Checks to see if the live message has already been sent.
                    #limit = 0
                    #limit += 1
                    async for message in channel.history(limit=2000):
                        # If it has, break the loop (do nothing).
                        if message.content == f"`Hey @everyone, {twitch_name} is live! Check it out:" + f"https://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}`":
                            break
                        # If it hasn't, assign them the streaming role and send the message.
                        else:
                            # Gets all the members in your guild.
                            async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
                                # If one of the id's of the members in your guild matches the one from the json and
                                # they're live, give them the streaming role.
                                if member.id == int(user_id):
                                    await member.add_roles(role)
                            # Sends the live notification to the 'twitch streams' channel then breaks the loop.
                            '''twitch_embed = discord.Embed(
                                title=f":red_circle: **LIVE**\n{user.name} is now streaming on Twitch!",
                                color=0xac1efb
                            )'''

                            #twitch_embed.add_field(name='**Game**', value='add value',inline=True)
                            #twitch_embed.add_field(name='**Viewers**', value='add value',inline=True)
                            #twitch_embed.set_image(url=f'\nhttps://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}')
                            
                            await channel.send(f"`Hey @everyone, {twitch_name} is live! Check it out:" + f"https://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}`")
                            #await channel.send(embed=twitch_embed)

                            print(f"{user} started streaming. Sending a notification.")
                            break
                # If they aren't live do this:
                else:
                    # Gets all the members in your guild.
                    async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
                        # If one of the id's of the members in your guild matches the one from the json and they're not
                        # live, remove the streaming role.
                        if member.id == int(user_id):
                            await member.remove_roles(role)
                    # Checks to see if the live notification was sent.
                    async for message in channel.history(limit=200):
                        # If it was, delete it.
                        if str(user.mention) in message.content and "is now streaming" in message.content:
                            await message.delete()
    # Start your loop.
    live_notifs_loop.start()


# Command to add Twitch usernames to the json.
@bot.command(name='addtwitch', help='Adds your Twitch to the live notifs.', pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def addtwitch(ctx, twitch_name):
    # Opens and reads the json file.
    with open('streamers.json', 'r') as file:
        streamers = json.loads(file.read())
    
    # Gets the users id that called the command.
    user_id = ctx.author.id
    # Assigns their given twitch_name to their discord id and adds it to the streamers.json.
    streamers[user_id] = twitch_name
    
    # Adds the changes we made to the json file.
    with open('streamers.json', 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(streamers))
    # Tells the user it worked.
    await ctx.send(f"Added {twitch_name} for {ctx.author} to the notifications list.")


ping()
bot.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

Edit:
Please say if something is not right or you don't understand the question instead of just closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the embed in the same message you can use `content` an example would be:

```py
await channel.send(content=f"`Hey @everyone, {twitch_name} is live! Check it out:" + f"https://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}`", embed=twitch_embed)
```

There would be no change in your check function as the message.content would be the same text message just with an embed as well.

You should really check if the stream has finished either by web scraping or some API instead of checking message content. If the stream finishes 3 hours ago but you only check for 2 streamers there won't be a change unless you have thought of this already.